# Create Native Client MediaStreamVideoTrack and send to javascript

Tags: google-nativeclient

According to the docs for the [Native Client MediaStreamVideoTrack](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/pepper_dev/cpp/classpp_1_1_media_stream_video_track#ad2d03ab8d65a7ca1b7f1528a07babdd6) there is a constructor that "Constructs a MediaStreamVideoTrack that outputs given frames to a new video track, which will be consumed by Javascript."

My idéa was then to put frames into this video track, that can later be displayed by javascript in a video tag or passed to a RTCPeerConnection.

I don't know if do it correctly, but from the docs for PostMessage states that it should be supported to pass a resource. But with the simple Native Client code below I only get a warning in the browser console: "Failed to convert a PostMessage argument from a PP_Var to a Javascript value. It may have cycles or be of an unsupported type."

```
virtual void HandleMessage(const pp::Var& var_message) {
    if (!var_message.is_dictionary()) {
      LogToConsole(PP_LOGLEVEL_ERROR, pp::Var("Invalid message!"));
      return;
    }

    pp::VarDictionary var_dictionary_message(var_message);
    std::string command = var_dictionary_message.Get("command").AsString();

    if (command == "create_track") {
      pp::MediaStreamVideoTrack video_track = pp::MediaStreamVideoTrack::MediaStreamVideoTrack(this);
      pp::VarDictionary dictionary;
      dictionary.Set(pp::Var("track"), pp::Var(video_track));
      PostMessage(dictionary);
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or something that isn't just supported? :)

Answer (score 0):

A MediaStreamVideoTrack can only be created by the page (not the plugin) and passed to the plugin by PostMessage. See this example code:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/examples/media_stream_video/media_stream_video.cc

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/ppapi/examples/media_stream_video/media_stream_video.html

Comment: Ok, and since a stream/track only can be created from getUserMedia I won't be able to manipulate the track since it's already filled by the camera stream then... :\

Comment: I want to render a mp4 file in MediaStreamVideoTrack , is it possible? if possible how? which method I called MediaStreamVideoTrack ?